# stub is not defined while testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, ruby-mocha

Suppose, I am running this test

```
Class MyModelTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase  
  def setup do
    @mymodel = MyModel.new
  end

  @mymodel.stub(:method).and_return { true }
```

but I get :`undefined method 'stub' for nil:NilClass`. I thought it was related to the `nil` instance, in fact when I dump with `@mymodel` with data, I get the same message `undefined method stub'`. Then I tried `@mymodel.stubs(:method).and_return { true }`, and I got this message

```
undefined method `and_return'
```

How can I solve that ?

Comment: Your original code is the `rspec` syntax, not `mocha` syntax

Comment: @UriAgassi in fact if I implement the above response and I replace `stub` by `stubs`, it works. How is it so ? and what is in my code `rspec` type code since it can work with the indicated modifications ?

Comment: Maybe I confused you with the word "syntax". I meant API. `stub`, `and_return` are APIs of the `rspec` library. `stubs` and `return` are part of the `mocha` API. (@MarekLipka had a typo in his answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@mymodel.stubs(:method).returns(true)
```

Comment: yes it passes indeed but if and only if I replace `stub` by `stubs`. Why is it so  ?

Comment: @user1611830 look at Uri Agassi's comment.